# Where/How do i set acks for kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Where can I set acks (acknowledgment) for producers in Kafka?
Can I do it in Cloudera Manager in the configuration for Kafka or is there some particular way to do that?
Also, how can I view the value of existing acks already being used?

I have checked the documentation [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs).
What it doesn't say, however, is how/where to set these options.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the documentation is pretty clear. The ack is a producer configuration parameter so you have to set the "acks" property (to 0, 1 or all) when you create the producer in your application and you need to provide the properties bag with all it's parameters (i.e. bootstrap brokers list, key serializer, value serializer and so on).
Ack is not a parameter related to the cluster itself or related to a specific broker, it's a parameter related to the producer so that you can have different producers with different acks.

Comment: Thank you.
is there a specific command to check the existing acks value using kafka command line.

Comment: You can see like this 

```bin/kafka-topics \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --describe  \
    --topic yourTopicName ```